# How can I make an Ionic popover to show above the trigger?

Tags: angular, user-interface, ionic-framework

I have an inline ionic popover:

```html
<!-- Show popover above trigger -->
<ion-button id="button">Demo</ion-button>
<ion-popover trigger="button" side="top">
  <ng-template>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>
          1. Test
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>
          2. Test
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>
          3. Test
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>
          4. Test
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-content>
  </ng-template>
</ion-popover>
```

And this is what it looks like:
[image]

I don't even see the other items as they are off screen.
So I was wondering if and how I can make the popover show above the trigger.

I tried the `side="top"`. It only makes the popover start at the upper corner of the trigger instead of at the lower corner, it does not seem to make the popover template appear above the trigger (in this case a simple ion-button).

---

Version info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.1 (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.1.9
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.0.0
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.3.5
   @angular/cli                  : 14.0.0
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.5.1
   @capacitor/android : not installed
   @capacitor/core    : 3.5.1
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : not installed globally
   native-run (update available: 1.6.0) : 1.5.0

System:

   NodeJS : v16.15.0 (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 8.5.5
   OS     : macOS Monterey
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for something like this.
You can find more about it here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover#inline-popover

```html
<!-- Show popover above trigger -->
<ion-button id="side-button">Click to open popover</ion-button>
<ion-popover trigger="side-button" side="top">
  <ng-template>
    <ion-content>Popover Content</ion-content>
  </ng-template>
</ion-popover>
```

EDIT: Not what you were looking for. Maybe it is possible to force the grow direction in css, but it doesn't seems to be a native property (I guess the grow "property" is relative to the space available downward).

**EDIT2**: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/popover-open-to-top-appearing-off-screen-on-bottom-of-a-page/219612/

Comment: I don't see how what you posted is different from what I have other than I am calling the present method programatically. 
I did read the docs. Right now the content goes OFF-screen. :|
What do you mean with `I guess the grow "property" is relative to the space available downward` ? I want the popover to show ABOVE the trigger.

Comment: Hey, sorry i was mistaken. After a few more researches, It seems to be an issue that was already reported to the ionic team. Updated the answer with a link to a thread with a fix
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24870

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with ion-popover in some specific cases (some specific elements used as triggers). It doesn't properly understand the side="top" attribute...

A workaround for it, is to use the --offset-y CSS property, on the popover element and move it up by as many pixels as you like so that its on screen.

```
<ion-popover class="myPopover" trigger="side-button" side="top">
```

CSS

```
.myPopover {
  --offset-y: -125px;
}
```

Of course you can change 125px to whatever suits your menu.